# How to slide the left(or right) menu back by touch with the project of slidingmenu/jfeinstein10?

Tags: android, user-interface, slidingmenu

How to slide the left(or right) menu back by touch   with the project of slidingmenu/jfeinstein10?

With slidingmenu/jfeinstein10,we can easily let the slidingmenu to come out by touching the main activity.But if we want to let the menu back or close,we should also touch the main(or center) fragment.So how should I do if I want close the slidingmenu by touching the menu fragment?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call the method `showContent()` in SlidingMenu to hide the menu and show the main activity.

Comment: But I want to hide the menu by slide the part of menu.Should I write another method like "OnTouch"?

Comment: for that try the method `setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN)`, though I haven't used it, try and let me know

Comment: Oh!Terrific!It's cool! I only use setTouchModeAbove() before and I ignore the method of setTouchModeBehind().Thank you very much!

Comment: But it got another problem.When I use setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN),all of the listener of the menu like onclicklistener has been ineffective.So what should I do then?Thank you

Comment: instead of TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN you can use TOUCHMODE_MARGIN

Comment: But if use TOUCHMODE_MARGIN instead,the problem nearly come back.Is there a menthod can both have the two function?Or maybe I should rewrite the framework

Comment: Well in that case you will need to modify the `CustomViewBehind` class maybe, I'll work on that too when I get time.